# Sending a GET/POST request in axios to receive a blob in React/Express Application

Tags: reactjs, express, post, get, axios

I have a youtubeVideos Downloader app and I have to send a get request(with URl) to download the video in react/express application.I am confused as to what to use Should I use GET or POST , If I Use GET have to use query paramaters which I dont like to use as I have to do extra work to make the url input by users that I have to escape the "?" and I thought of Using Post with req.body.url so then I can use it in my route handler . I need help which way to go ? 
My index.js file in express :

```
app.post('/api/getmevideo', async (req, res) => {



    try {
        const videoURL = req.body.url;
        const videoName = await downloadVideoAsync(videoURL);
        const videoPath = path.join(__dirname + `/videos/${videoName}.mp4`);
        res.sendFile(videoPath, function() {
            fs.unlinkSync(videoPath);
        });
    }
    catch(ex) {
        res.send({
            message : "something went wrong"
        })
    }



  });
```

My Axios code in App.js in React :

```
downloadHandler() {
         if(this.state.inputText !== '') {
                axios({
                        url: '/api/getmevideo',
                        method: 'POST',
                        responseType: 'blob', // important
                    }, { url : this.state.inputText }).then((response) => {
                            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
                            const link = document.createElement('a');
                            link.href = url;
                             link.setAttribute('download', 'video.mp4'); 
                            document.body.appendChild(link);
                            link.click();
                        });
                    }
    }
```

Thanks!